Видимость функций и блоков в JavaScript
Суть вопроса:
Имеется два скрипта: head.js и body.js, которые вызываются, в соответствии со своим названием, в конце <head> и в конце <body>. В head.js содержится функция quote(text), которая должна менять содержимое блока с id="quote". Вызывается эта функция в body.js, но происходит ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText') - т.е. блок для этой функции не виден. Прошу объяснить почему работает так, как оно работает, и не сильно пинать увечного (В js я дилетант с минимальным опытом).
Просто в том же head.js имеется другая функция, которая также меняет содержимое страницы (блока <main>), но вызывается уже изнутри самого <main> по onclick="...", и с ней всё работает идеально, а тут мне не понятно, что происходит, т.к. эта функция вызывается даже уже после нужного ей блока и должна его видеть, но null, однако...
Код:
head.js
function quote(text) {
    document.querySelector("#quote").innerText = text;
}

body.js
quote("Какой-то текст...");

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="./head.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div id='head'><div id="quote"></div></div>
    </header>
    <main>
    </main>
    <script src="./body.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


В document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){} оборачивали js код из body.js?

@ЕвгенийЛи ну вообще, гипотетически, располагая скрипты в самом конце тега body, мы уже полагаем, что html был весь прогружен. Иначе бы до тега script дело бы не дошло. Или я ошибаюсь?

@ЕвгенийЛи, добрый день, я просто такую конструкцию не использую. Если ваш вопрос связан со второй функцией, то она вызывается через указание атрибута onсlick соответствующему тегу. Иначе не понимаю о чём вы.

Функция из head.js хоть и вызывается из body.js... Но возможно сам контент грузится так же динамически и его все еще нет на странице на момент вызова функции.

Проверил пример - всё работает. Вероятно, проблема в том, что есть ещё какой-то скрипт, который удаляет элемент #quote. Откройте в браузере панель разработчика и проверьте, что в нужный момент элемент присутствует на странице.


Прошу объяснить почему работает так, как оно работает

Проиллюстрирую ответ примером с комментариями. Надеюсь, что будет понятно.


<script>
function quote(text) {
  document.querySelector("#quote").innerText = text;
}
/*
Это работать не будет, т.к. еще нет нужного элемента
quote('Ok')
*/
// Вот так будет работать
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => quote('Ok'))
</script>
<p id='quote'></p>
<!-- Это работает, т.к. на момент нажатия на кнопку уже все элементы есть на странице --->
<button onclick='quote("Тест")'>Тест</button>



Вот твой пример...


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>
function quote(text) {
  document.querySelector("#quote").innerText = text;
}
</script>    
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div id='head'><div id="quote"></div></div>
    </header>
    <main>
    </main>
<script>
quote('Ok')
</script>
</body>

</html>



Все там работает.
Значит ты не все рассказал нам про формирование твоей страницы.
Возможно твой контент так же создается динамически. Т.о. возможно, что на момент вызова функции элементов еще нет на странице.

Прикол то в том, что контент динамический только в одном блоке, а нужный блок <div id="quote"> как появился на странице, так я его и не трогаю (он находится вне динамического блока, ровно перед ним на том же уровне) (за исключением проблемной функции) UPD: блоком с динамическим содержимым является <main>

@AndreyMozharov, я специально взял твой пример и показал, что там все работает. Если все так как ты рассказываешь. Но, скорее всего, "есть нюансы"... Какие именно я пока не знаю, ты их не показываешь в своем примере.

Перепроверил и оказалось, что, действительно, всё из-за нюансов... благодарю за потраченное время

В итоге я был прав). Просто постоянно с этим сталкиваюсь, когда пишу js, jQuery.
